# How can I share low-level utility classes between packages but not expose it to the public API?

Tags: java, package

I have a library project and I want to limit the public API but I also have some low-level utility classes that are shared among some of the packages. I need these utility classes to be publicly accessible, but I do not want to expose them in the library's public API.

I thought about doing reflection but it seems a little to messy for this application.

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Don't include these classes in the documentation of the API, or document them with a bold warning: **This class is for internal use only and is subject to changes or removal in future versions of the API. Don't use it**.

Putting these classes in a `com.foo.bar.internal` package is also useful.

Comment: this is what apache does for instance

Comment: We were thinking about using an internal .internal package but didn't know if that would make sense

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that your utility classes are in different packages, else you could have used the package protected visibility.

If performance is not a concern, you can build the stack trace ([Thread.currentThread.getStackTrace()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Thread.html#getStackTrace%28%29)) in your utility class' constructor. Then you can inspect the call stack for the caller of the constructor and throw a runtime exception if the "immediate" caller is not from your library's package/class.